# How do I get the 7th grandma in cookie clicker

Tags: cookie-clicker

I have over 100 grandmas and have shipments, but IDK what the 7th grandma is in cookie clicker and IDK what it is, can someone please tell me?

Answer (score 9):

You need 7 different grandma types, not just 7 grandmas. The different types unlocks when you reach 15 of each of the other buildings.

Read more here https://cookieclicker.fandom.com/wiki/Upgrades#Grandma_types